# DSolve of second order DE results in InverseFunction

Tags: differential-equations

As a result of evaluating

```
DSolve[a''[t] a[t] - (1 - C) a'[t]^2 + (Cc - C L/3) a[t]^2 + (C - 1) k/2 == 0, a[t], t]
```

I got an `InverseFunction`. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: (1) Mathematica cannot solve the integral so I think you are stuck with it. (2) The symbol C is a protected built-in symbol that users should avoid using as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Solution by `Solve`:

I changed the letter `C` to `M`.

```
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve}, Unprotect[Solve];
 Solve[x___] := Block[{$guard = True}, Print["Solve called : ", HoldForm[Solve[x]]];
 Solve[x]] /; ! TrueQ[$guard];
 DSolve[a''[t] a[t] - (1 - M) a'[t]^2 + (Cc - M L/3) a[t]^2 + (M - 1) k/2 == 0, a[t], t]];

 (*long output*)
```

The last line of output is:

```
 Solve[Inactive[Integrate][(Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[M])/Sqrt[-3*k*M - 6*Cc*K[2]^2 + 2*L*M*K[2]^2 + 6*M*C[1]*K[2]^(2 - 2*M)], 
{K[2], 1, a[t]}] == t + C[2], a[t]]
```

Solution by **Maple**:

[image]

Maple can't find closed form for this integral:(.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $u = a^c$ transforms the OP's ODE into (with $c=C$)
$$u''/c + (C_c -c L/3)\,u + {(c-1)k \over  2} {u^{1-2/c}}=0\,.$$
This can be put in the form
$$u'' + a\,u = b\,u^p \quad (p = 1-2/c) \tag{1}$$
or more generally
$$u'' + a\,u = f(u)\,. \tag{2}$$

Here is a check in *Mathematica*:

```
odeOP = a''[t] a[t] - (1 - C) a'[t]^2 + (Cc - C L/3) a[t]^2 + (C - 1) k/2 /. C -> c;

(* u[t] == a[t]^c *)
odeU = u''[t]/c + (Cc - c L/3) u[t] + (c - 1) k/2 u[t]^(1 - 2/c);
backsub = odeU /. u -> (a[#]^c &) // PowerExpand // Simplify;  (* assumes a[t] > 0 *)
a[t]^(2 - c) backsub - odeOP // Simplify
(*  0  <-- No difference other than the factor a[t]^(2 - c) *)
```

Now let's try to solve ODEs (1) and (2):

```
DSolve[u''[t] + a u[t] == b u[t]^p, u, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[u''[t] + a u[t] == f[u[t]], u, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first solution shows that unless $1+p = 2-2/c$ is a rational number in a fairly limited range, the integral in the equation won't be evaluated.  For several values of $p$ (integers between $-2$ and $5$, $\pm 1/2$, $1/3$), the integral can be calculated but the equation cannot be solved. The only case I've found the ODE can be solved is $p=1$ (obviously, if you think about it), but $c$ is undefined. The case $p=-1$ might seem possible, and in a sense it is. The `(b K[1]^(1 + p))/(1 + p)` term becomes `b Log[K[1]]` when `p = -1`, and the integral cannot be found; however, the corresponding value of $c$ is $c=1$, which gets rid of the nonlinear term and allows the OP's ODE to be solved.

In short, as I said in my comment, you are probably stuck with the implicit solutions (or the one in terms of `InverseFunction`, which is practically the same thing).

Comment: This gives us a transcendental equation, which can only be solved numerically. I mean, we first Plot and then FindRoot.

Comment: @AbdelNasserTawfik Yes that is my point in a way (“stuck with implicit solutions”) although I left open how to deal with the integral and equation because the several unspecified parameters open up various routes of analysis